# Calculating a running total of when a value changes over a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am having trouble figuring out how to write a window function that solves my problem. I am quite the novice at window functions, but I think one could be written to meet my needs.

**Problem Statement:**

I want to calculate a transfer sequence showing when person has changed locations based on the corresponding location ID over time.

**Sample Data (Table1)**

```
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| PersonID | LocationID | Date      | Time    |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 12       | A          | 6/17/2020 | 12:00PM |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 12       | A          | 6/18/2020 | 1:00PM  |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 12       | B          | 6/18/2020 | 6:00AM  |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 12       | C          | 6/19/2020 | 3:00PM  |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 8:00AM  |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 11:00AM |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 12:00AM |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 13       | B          | 6/16/2020 | 4:00PM  |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

**Expected Results**

```
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| PersonID | LocationID | Date      | Time    | Transfer Sequence |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 12       | A          | 6/17/2020 | 12:00PM | 1                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 12       | A          | 6/18/2020 | 1:00PM  | 1                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 12       | B          | 6/18/2020 | 6:00AM  | 2                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 12       | C          | 6/19/2020 | 3:00PM  | 3                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 8:00AM  | 1                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 11:00AM | 1                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 13       | A          | 6/16/2020 | 12:00AM | 1                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| 13       | B          | 6/16/2020 | 4:00PM  | 2                 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+
```

**What I Tried**

```
SELECT 
     [t1].[PersonID]
    ,[t1].[LocationID]
    ,[t1].[Date]
    ,[t1].[Time]
    ,DENSE_RANK() 
         OVER( 
           partition BY [t1].[PersonID], [t1].[LocationID] 
           ORDER BY [t1].[Date] ASC, [t1].[Time] ASC) AS 
       [Transfer Sequence]


FROM Table1 [t1]
```

Unfortunately, I believe DENSE_RANK() is assigning a rank regardless of whether the value of LocationID has changed. I need a function that will only add one to the sequence when the LocationID has changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put "adjacent" rows in the same group. Straigt window functions cannot do that for you - we would need to use a gaps-and-island technique:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    sum(case when locationID = lagLocationID then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(partition by personID order by date, time) 
        as transfert_sequence
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(locationID) 
            over(partition by personID order by date, time) 
            as lagLocationID
    from mytable t
) t
```

The idea is to compute a window sum that increments everytime the locationID changes.

Note that this would properly handle the case when a person comes back to a location they have already been before.

Answer (score 1):

What wuold I do (and I'm sure it's not the best way) is create a second table orderd with PersonID, locationID, Date, time and and empty field for the transfer sequence (sequence), then a cursor:

```
DECLARE transaction CURSOR
FOR select PersonID, LocationID, Date, Time from table1;
```

Then a loop:

```
OPEN CURSOR transaction
set @count = 0
set @person_saved = ""
set @location_saed = ""
FETCH NEXT FROM transaction INTO @person, @location, @date, @time

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
if @person_saved <> @person  -- changing personID, reset count
begin
set count = 0
set persone_saved = @person
end
if @location_saved <> @location. -- changing location, add count
begin
set @count = @count + 1
set @location_saved = @location
end
update table1 set sequence = @count where PersonId = @person and locationId = @location and date = @date and time = @time

FETCH NEXT FROM transaction INTO @person, @location, @date, @time
END

CLOSE transaction
DEALLOCATE transaction
```

Comment: Is a cursor approach more efficient than using subqueries to solve this type of problem?

Comment: In time of performance depends on how many row the table have, the plus for which i normaly use cursor is debugging... a stored procedure with a cursor is easyer to debug then an SQL. Sure, if the SQL from @GMB works fine, is a lot less to write :)